Redis task queues
I am new to Redis Queue and I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://blog.abbasmj.com/implementing-redis-task-queues-and-deploying-on-docker-compose.
The problem I have is that at container startup, the flask-app container exists with code 0 and no log message. What I am missing?
docker compose up --remove-orphans
WARN[0000] /home/..../Redis/tutorial/docker-compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
[+] Running 4/0
 ✔ Container tutorial-redis-1-1  Removed                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container tutorial-redis-1    Created                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container tutorial-worker-1   Created                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container flask-app           Created                                                                                                            0.0s 
Attaching to flask-app, redis-1, worker-1
redis-1    | 1:C 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.338 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-1    | 1:C 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.339 * Redis version=7.4.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-1    | 1:C 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.339 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.339 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * Server initialized
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.4.0
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * RDB age 19 seconds
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * RDB memory usage when created 1.35 Mb
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 1, keys expired: 0.
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis-1    | 1:M 20 Sep 2024 11:23:28.340 * Ready to accept connections tcp
worker-1   | 11:23:28 Worker rq:worker:d6a752b63cae48cbb7e3ebf00bf5318e started with PID 1, version 1.16.2
worker-1   | 11:23:28 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:d6a752b63cae48cbb7e3ebf00bf5318e
worker-1   | 11:23:28 *** Listening on default...
worker-1   | 11:23:28 Cleaning registries for queue: default
flask-app exited with code 0

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
            - ./redis:/redis

    flask-app:
        image: app-image
        depends_on:
            - redis
        container_name: flask-app
        build: app
        #restart: always
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app

    worker:
        image: app-image:latest
        depends_on:
            - redis
            # - flask-app
        command: rq worker --url redis://redis:6379
        # links:
        #     - redis

api.py
    import time 
    import requests
    
    def getCatImage(delay):
    
        # Simulate Delay
        time.sleep(delay)
    
        url = requests.get(
            "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").json()[0]['url']
    
        # Result
        return url
    

app.py
from flask import Flask
import redis
from rq import Queue
from api import getCatImage

app = Flask(__name__)

r = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
q = Queue(connection=r)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    task = q.enqueue(getCatImage, 5)
    n = len(q.jobs)

    html = '<center><br /><br />'
    for job in q.jobs:
        html += f'<a href="job/{job.id}">{job.id}</a><br /><br />'
    html += f'Total {n} Jobs in queue </center>'
    return f"{html}"


@app.route('/job/<job_id>')
def getJob(job_id):

    res = q.fetch_job(job_id)

    if not res.result:
        return f'<center><br /><br /><h3>The job is still pending</h3><br /><br />ID:{job_id}<br />Queued at: {res.enqueued_at}<br />Status: {res._status}</center>'

    return f'<center><br /><br /><img src="{res.result}" height="200px"><br /><br />ID:{job_id}<br />Queued at: {res.enqueued_at}<br />Finished at: {res.ended_at}</center>'

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]



Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Without seeing any source code it's hard to guess what might be going on.

The code is in the link above. I will copy it here as well but the problem appear immediately when I start the containers with docker compose.

Just the Compose file isn't enough to debug this.  What is in app/Dockerfile, and more specifically, what is its CMD line?  Does overwriting the image content with volumes: cause the problem?  If the CMD runs a Python script, what is its main function?

Please view the code in the question. Main function is app.py

It seems like you're missing an app.run() call.  If you run ./app.py in your non-Docker virtual environment, does it start the server, or does it just exit immediately?

(This needs a specific invocation in Docker, since the Flask dev server normally starts up in a way that's unreachable from outside its own container; see Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues.)

@DavidMaze I've got it. Thank you so much.

You need to add thos 2 lines at the end of you app.py. if name == "main":
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
